# Spritekit Animate Textures, or Nodes for performance?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, animation, sprite-kit, paintcode

Just wondering if anyone knows which has better performance, when the result is pretty much the same? For example, the situation I am working on is animating a character's face. I have two ways of doing this that should look pretty much the same:

1) Create a series of SKTextures and cache them in an array. When I am ready to animate, I run

```
[SKAction animateWithTextures...
```

Using PaintCode for this, so no worries about using extra space for extra images.

2) Create a few SKSpriteNodes as a heirarchy. Each SKSpriteNode has a static image. Then run things like

```
[SKAction moveTo...
```

I know each of these has their own advantages in terms of the end result and the time it takes to implement, but which is better in terms of performance? Animating a sequence of images, or moving a bunch of nodes around and having SpriteKit render the images?

My thoughts are that 
1) Animating textures may be faster because images have already been precached.
2) Moving nodes around may be faster because SpriteKit may know to only render parts of images that have a change in display.

So not sure, but was hoping someone else may.

Comment: 1)  Animating textures may be faster but required two many textures in memory

Comment: This question is touch to answer, because it is way to vague.  The answer could be a combination of both,  A set of SKNodes that have smaller animating textures.